# Is it possible to make C++ iostream std::cout be as performant as cstdio printf()?

Tags: c++, synchronization, iostream, cstdio

Note: This is not a duplicate of existing `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` questions. I have gone through all of them and yet I am unable to make `cout` behave as fast as `printf`. Example code and evidence shown below.

I have three source code files:

```cpp
// ex1.cpp

#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%lld\n", duration.count());
}
```

```cpp
// ex2.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cerr << duration.count() << '\n';
}
```

```cpp
// ex3.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cerr << duration.count() << '\n';
}
```

I am not going to ever mix `cstdio` and `iostream` in my code, so the hacks used in `ex3.cpp` are okay for me.

I compile them with clang++ on macOS with solid-state drive.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ex1.cpp -o ex1
```

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ex2.cpp -o ex2
```

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ex3.cpp -o ex3
```

Now I run them and time them.

```
$ time ./ex1 > out.txt
1282

real    0m1.294s
user    0m1.217s
sys     0m0.071s

$ time ./ex1 > out.txt
1299

real    0m1.333s
user    0m1.221s
sys     0m0.072s

$ time ./ex1 > out.txt
1277

real    0m1.295s
user    0m1.214s
sys     0m0.070s
```

```
$ time ./ex2 > out.txt
3102

real    0m3.371s
user    0m3.037s
sys     0m0.075s

$ time ./ex2 > out.txt
3153

real    0m3.164s
user    0m3.073s
sys     0m0.075s

$ time ./ex2 > out.txt
3136

real    0m3.150s
user    0m3.051s
sys     0m0.077s
```

```
$ time ./ex3 > out.txt
3118

real    0m3.513s
user    0m3.045s
sys     0m0.080s

$ time ./ex3 > out.txt
3113

real    0m3.124s
user    0m3.042s
sys     0m0.077s

$ time ./ex3 > out.txt
3095

real    0m3.107s
user    0m3.029s
sys     0m0.073s
```

The results are quite similar even if I redirect the output to `/dev/null`. The results are quite similar with `-O3` optimization level too.

Both `ex3` and `ex2` are slower than `ex1`? Is it possible to use `std::cout` in anyway that gives comparable speed with `printf`?

Comment: My question for you is: Why is this a problem? What are you doing that leads to output being such a major bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a problem because I don't understand why the results I am getting are inconsistent with other answers on this topic. I am not doing anything that leads to output being a bottleneck. I am trying to understand if disabling synchronization with `stdio` does indeed lead to the side effect of better performance or not, and if not, why not?

Comment: It may be worth timing inside the program itself. It may be that (for example) a lot more code gets put into the binary, so the start-up time is longer?

Comment: I'm just not getting the same results as you tbh. In my tests they get progressively faster. `0m1.309s`, `0m1.274s` and `0m1.041s` respectively. (GCC v10 though).

Comment: Although my results are rather variable on a HDD rather than the SDD. I would have thought the majority of the time spent on this is Disk-IO rather than the C++ libraries.

Comment: Maybe you could try outputting to `/dev/null`?

Comment: With my setup (g++ 9.3.0 via WSL, SSD, compiled with -o3, each test run multiple times but seperately) the first an second version take rouglhy the _same time_ whereas the third one takes _half_ the time (so it's actually faster then printf on my platform). So, maybe your disk speed is screwing the meassurement? Or the implementation? Going to test this with Visual studio next.

Comment: @Galik Thank you for the comments. I have added timing inside the program now in the tests and updated the question too to include internal timing data. Redirecting the output to `/dev/null` also produces similar timing results. For example, `time ./ex1 > /dev/null` consumed 1204 ms, `time ./ex2 > /dev/null` consumed 3368 ms and `time ./ex3 > /dev/null` consumed 3311 ms in one of the trial runs.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks for the comment! I had that in the original question and then forgot it after an update. I have added the `-O2` option back to the tests now and updated the results as well.

Comment: @Galik @churill Confirmed that with `g++ 8.3.0` on Linux, I get similar results as yours. `ex1` takes about 1100 ms, `ex2` takes about 1300 ms and `ex3` takes about 1000 ms. So the issue in my question looks like an issue in `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)` that is on my macOS system.